# How to set Object instance value equal null if there is no data found in Left Join in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have Linq query in which I am apply left join for respondent table, to see if the user detail is there or not! if detail is there then get user record which is working else if user record is not there set null value and I am struggling to set null value here. I am using autoMapper to convert dataModel to dataView. In linq query, refer to 'User' property, also attached screen shot of output I am getting at the movement

### LINQ Query

```
var responsesList3 = (from response in Context.Responses
                              where response.ConsultationId == ConsultationId && response.ResponseTypeId == ResponseTypeId && response.ResponseCurrentStatus == ResponseStatusType
                              join respondent in Context.Respondents.Include(resp => resp.User) on response.RespondentId equals respondent.Id
                              //from respondentUser in Context.Users.Where(user => user.Id == respondent.UserId) 
                              join respondentUser in Context.Users on respondent.UserId equals respondentUser.Id into rs
                              from respondentUserDetail in rs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join responseType in Context.ResponseTypes on response.ResponseTypeId equals responseType.Id
                              join dataEntryAnalyst in Context.Users on response.DataEntryAnalystId equals dataEntryAnalyst.Id
                              select new ResponseDataView
                              {
                                  ResponseId = response.Id,
                                  RespondentId = response.RespondentId,
                                  Respondent = new RespondentDataView
                                  {
                                      RespondentId = respondent.Id,
                                      UserId = respondent.UserId,
                                      // User = respondent.UserId == null ? null : Context.Users.Where(user => user.Id == respondent.UserId).AsQueryable().ProjectTo<UserDataView>(),
                                      // User = respondent.UserId == null ?  : My.Mapper.Map<UserDataView>(respondent.User),
            //(need to set User = null if Respondent.UserId ==null)???????????
                                      User =  My.Mapper.Map<UserDataView>(respondentUserDetail),
                                      Name = respondent.Name,
                                      Organisation = respondent.Organisation,
                                      Address = respondent.Address,
                                      Stakeholder = respondent.Stakeholder,
                                      GenderType = respondent.GenderType
                                  }

                             }
     );
```

### Respondent DataView

```
public struct RespondentDataView
{
    public Guid RespondentId { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public UserDataView User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Organisation { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Stakeholder { get; set; }
    public GenderTypes GenderType { get; set; }
}
```

### UserDataView

```
  public struct UserDataView
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

### User Mapping

```
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<UserDataModel, UserDataView>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Surname))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Email))
            ;


    }
```

Comment: You have `UserDataView` as a struct so it won't be null.

Comment: I just figure out too, is any way I can make struct nullable?

Comment: Unless there's a reason it's a struct, consider making it a class

Comment: Otherwise, you can make it nullable `Nullable<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is due to struct as my dataView, solution change struct to Nullable or in my case, I change it to class

```
public class UserDataView
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and in linq query, check for null value as

```
//remain code of linq continuous ......
Respondent = new RespondentDataView
                                  {
                                      RespondentId = respondent.Id,
                                      UserId = respondent.UserId,
                                      User = respondent.UserId == null ? null: My.Mapper.Map<UserDataView>(respondentUserDetail),
                                      Name = respondent.Name,
                                      Organisation = respondent.Organisation,
                                      Address = respondent.Address,
                                      Stakeholder = respondent.Stakeholder,
                                      GenderType = respondent.GenderType
                                  }
```